# How can I say: “I still don't speak French as well as I understand”

Tags: choix-de-mot

Maybe I could translate it as following:

> Je ne parle toujours pas le français aussi bien que je comprends.

Comment: This will be understood but to be correct it should be "...que je le comprends."

Comment: Even in English, I'd say "as I understand *it*".

Answer (score 2):

For simple translations like this one could use Google Translate or better DeepL. E.g., the latter gives for you :

https://www.deepl.com/translator#fr/en/Je%20ne%20parle%20toujours%20pas%20aussi%20bien%20le%20fran%C3%A7ais%20que%20je%20le%20comprends.

> Je ne parle toujours pas aussi bien le français que je le comprends.

Note that this particular translator gives correctly the neutral pronoun *le* (see the comment of the user @Laurent S.).

Following the comment of @Luke Sawczak, I entered

> I still don't speak French as well as I understand **it**.

into Google Translate. It gives the proper translation as well.

Comment: Yes. I was wondering if I could ask such question here or not. I think I can't fully trust Google Translate. I've never heard about DeepL. For example, my translated phrase on Google Translate doesn't have the neutral pronoun, whereas in DeepL it has the neutral pronoun. If I translated another phrase, and both those applications gave me different answers, what do you think I should do?

Comment: By the way, if I translate my phrase *“I still don't speak French as well as I understand”*, I get a "toujours" which your phrase doesn't have. Maybe you missed the *"still"*?

Comment: @Kaldwin With _toujours_, your phrase would translate into "Je ne parle toujours pas aussi bien le français que je le comprends".

Comment: @Kaldwin: See my updated answer. In general this type of question risks to be closed. See here https://french.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @Kaldwin > Dimitris probably overlooked the "still" in your example. The nuance between one and the other is as thin in French as it is in English.

Comment: @LaurentS. I modified my answer and I added *still*.  Thanks for your comments.